# Interpolation between 2d-data to create a 3d-surface?

Tags: python, interpolation

I have several data rows from measurements with x/y-data which I would like to represent as a 2d-surface/3d-surface. For a short test I wrote the following demo script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import h5py
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.numeric import full
import scipy.constants as scco
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, freqz
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Cairo')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate, optimize

from PIL import Image, PngImagePlugin

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

import math
from string import Template
import subprocess

import types
import functools

from enum import Enum
import sys

first_position = 2
second_position = 4
third_position = 6

x_vec = np.linspace(0, 10, 1024)

def gen_function(x_vec, f_pos, factor):
    return np.exp(-np.power(x_vec - f_pos, factor))

first_vec = gen_function(x_vec, first_position, 32)
second_vec = gen_function(x_vec, second_position, 8)
third_vec = gen_function(x_vec, third_position, 2)

plt.plot(x_vec, first_vec)
plt.plot(x_vec, second_vec)
plt.plot(x_vec, third_vec)
plt.show()

ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="3d")
ax.plot(x_vec, np.ones(x_vec.size) * first_position * 0.1, first_vec)
ax.add_collection3d(plt.fill_between(x_vec, 0.95 * first_vec, 1.05 * first_vec, alpha=0.3), zs = first_position, zdir='y')
ax.plot(x_vec, np.ones(x_vec.size) * second_position * 0.1, second_vec)
ax.add_collection3d(plt.fill_between(x_vec, 0.95 * second_vec, 1.05 * second_vec, alpha=0.3), zs = second_position, zdir='y')
ax.plot(x_vec, np.ones(x_vec.size) * third_position * 0.1, third_vec)
ax.add_collection3d(plt.fill_between(x_vec, 0.95 * third_vec, 1.05 * third_vec, alpha=0.3), zs = third_position, zdir='y')
plt.show()
```

Here, `x_vec` represents my x-data from my measurements, and the vectors `first_vec`, `second_vec` and `third_vec` represent example y data. When executing it, I get
[image]
I would now like to find a way to interpolate the empty space in between, such that I either can have a 3d-surface plot instead, or reduce the data to a 2d-surface plot. What could I use for that?